# checkboxes in content type

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, content-type

## update

I created a content type: periode in this type I created a field training days: now I want that a user can choose monday: and select morning or afternoon (checkbox) the same for thursday and other days in the week.

My goal is that I have a title Monday and that I can select morning and/or afternoon. And this for all day's of the week.[image]

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit?

Comment: sorry! I updated, thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enable the option widget of cck then you will be able to select check box.

Comment: but, I need a label Monday then the user can select morning and or afternoon.

Comment: I think you need two input fields one for the days and one for the time of the days. so you can use select box for days and checkbox for time.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way of nicely ordering checkboxes in this way with the default creation of forms with cck check boxes.

To get this kind of result in the most professional manner, you will need to dip into Drupal's Form API with hook_form_alter - which can seem complicated if you aren't used to using Drupal hooks, but is not all that difficult if you have some knowledge of PHP.  See http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6.  This would entail writing a small module yourself for this purpose.  Lullabot's tutorial on this matter is very good: http://www.lullabot.com/articles/modifying-forms-drupal-5-and-6

If you can't do this, your option would be to simply make two checkboxes per day, e.g. Monday Morning, Monday Afternoon, etc. etc..